# maven "project.resources.sourceEncoding"

Tags: maven

I have this in an example pom file:

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<!-- cannot find project.resources.sourceEncoding in maven documentation -->
<project.resources.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.resources.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

Is `project.resources.sourceEncoding` an official maven property? I cannot find it in the documentation.

Comment: Maybe you mean something like this: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-model-builder/#Model_Interpolation

Comment: No, I want to know if `project.resources.sourceEncoding` is an **official** maven property like `project.build.sourceEncoding` (which is an official property).

Comment: Have you found an explanation for `project.resources.sourceEncoding`. The answer is no. Nor the [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) contains something like this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html):

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

> By using the above property **maven-resources-plugin** will
>   automatically use this encoding.

So `project.resources.sourceEncoding` is not an official maven property (maybe it was one in the past in combination with *maven-resources-plugin*), but it is not needed and has no affect in the maven procedure.